# Different validation process for JPA saving and form validation with same entity class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an user entity class which is mapped by table in my database. In that class, there is `password` field like:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "...")
public class UserEntity {

    ...

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 64)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 8, max = 64)
    private String password;

    ...
}
```

This class represents an user in whole project source codes.

But the problem is the registration process:

1. Client passes a password in registration form
2. Controller validates user password with `@Valid`
3. Service **encodes** password by encrypt algorithm.
4. Service tries to save an user by calling repository's `save()`
5. Then just before saving it into the database, validation occurs again
6. User now saved into the database

There are two validation process, a form validation and an entity validation.

But they should have different validation strategies.

I've already implemented two different validators with related constraint annotations.

What is the most simple way to make it do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Validation (RI for Bean Validation) allow `validation groups`

The example below validate all the fields in Car object

```
UserEntity user = ...
Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(user);
```

But, what if I want to validate some fields in my first step and other fields in the second step? Here is where `Validation Groups` enter in action

```
constraintViolations = validator.validate(user, Step1.class);

constraintViolations = validator.validate(user, Step2.class);
```

Now, your `UserEntity` should be modified

```
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 64)
@NotNull(groups = Step1.class)
@Size(min = 8, max = 64, groups = Step2.class)
private String password;
```

So, in the first step, password will be validated to be not null meanwhile in step 2 the validation will be that the size's minimum is 8 and the maximum 64.